# Version control of database records

Tags: mysql, version-control

I had no idea what to call this because it is actually the first time ive ever come across this issue. However i believe that other people than me have had this issue. I am therefore looking for an elegant solution.

My example:

First some background, im running an application that allows users to create Powerpoint like "Modules" for their clients to see.

To control these i have the following two database tables:

**Module**

```
Table: module
Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
name    varchar(75)
description text
category_id int(11)
module_type_id  int(11) PK
gives_score tinyint(4)
duration    varchar(70)
price   varchar(45)
score_to_pass   int(11)
gives_certificate   int(11)
is_rtl  int(11)
price_6_month   varchar(45)
price_12_month  varchar(45)
is_active   int(11)
is_in_focus int(11)
caption text
```

**module_component**

```
Table: module_component
Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
text    text
sound_path  text
video_flv_path  text
video_mp4_path  text
image_path  text
document_path   text
sort_number int(11)
component_type_id   int(11)
question_id int(11)
question_type_id    int(11)
module_id   int(11) PK
content_type    varchar(100)
```

Now sometimes in these modules our costumer wants to ask question (hence the `question_id` in the table `module_component`)

So for the sake of having all the data here is the `question table`:

**question**

```
Table: question
Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
question    text
question_type_id    int(11) PK
```

**question_answer**

```
Table: question_answer
Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
answer  text
is_correct  int(11)
question_id int(11) PK
question_question_type_id   int(11) PK
```

Okay now to the exact issue:

The problem is that sometimes these modules content needs to be changed either the company who owns them has new updated policies or a new question or video content needs to be added.

However if we just were to change the current module and its components all who has already taken the module would have corrupt data.

Further more a need for different languages have occoured.

So taking this to the next step i needed to do something like this:

[image]

Then when someone changes the module something similar will happen:

[image]

Now it is easy to see that within a small amount of time a lot of redundant data will be kept in the database.
My question is, is what i am proposing the best option when it comes to version control of this scale. Or are there tools / methods that makes something like this easier?

The above method (that i show) is basicly just copy and paste per version.

**Simplified database diagram**

Here is a simple image that shows how the database diagram currently looks  (without the unnecessary columns for this question)

[image]